# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 dynamic infowindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am adding markers dynamically like this:

```
var oldMarkers = null;
    return function(map, locations){
        //Clearing markers, if they exist
        if(oldMarkers && oldMarkers.length !== 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < oldMarkers.length; ++i){
                oldMarkers[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
        //Adding new markers
        oldMarkers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var newmarker = locations[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newmarker[1], newmarker[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: myLatLng,
               map: map,
               shape: shape,
               title: newmarker[0],
               zIndex: newmarker[3],
               clickable: true
            });
oldMarkers.push( marker );
 }
```

Works well based on a jQuery "click"  function.  What I would like to do now is add an  infowindow to each marker.  OK I have this code from Google which should/does go before `oldMarkers.push( marker )`:

```
var j = i + 1;
marker.setTitle(j.toString());
attachSecretMessage(marker, j);
```

and this function:

```
function attachSecretMessage(marker, number) {
  var message = ["This","is","the","secret","message"];
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
      { content: message[number],
        size: new google.maps.Size(50,50)
      });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}
```

It sort of works, in that an info box appears for 2 markers where it should do, but not for all.  This is what/where I don't understand:  If I have an array to make new markers like this (only an example):

```
var essentials = [
['Marker 1', 12.254181, 12.649962 , 9],
['Marker 2', 12.254181, 12.649962 , 9],
['Marker 3', 12.254181, 12.649962 , 9],
['Marker 4', 12.254181, 12.649962 , 9],
}
```

What I need/would like to do is add an array key for the content of the infowindow so a bit like this:

```
 var essentials = [
    ['Marker 1', 12.254181, 12.649962 , 9, 'Info Window content']
```

How do I pass `newmarker[4]` to the infowindow?

Answer (score 1):

OMG I'm being think! - just add  `attachSecretMessage ( marker, newmarker[4] );` ooops! as said being thick! sorry